# Why does JavaFX contain duplicate color constants?

Tags: java, javafx

Looking at the API documentation for [JavaFX 11](https://openjfx.io/) I found that it contains duplicate color constants. For example:

- [DARKGRAY](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#DARKGRAY) - The color dark gray with an RGB value of `#A9A9A9`
- [DARKGREY](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#DARKGREY) - The color dark grey with an RGB value of `#A9A9A9`

and

- [GRAY](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#GRAY) - The color gray with an RGB value of `#808080`
- [GREY](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#GREY) - The color grey with an RGB value of `#808080`

As you can see the only difference is in the spelling of the field names, but not the RGB values. Do you know why there are such duplicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do you know why there are such duplicates?

Because there are alternate spellings of the word "grey" in English.

- [Gray or Grey?](https://www.dictionary.com/e/gray-or-grey/)

This is simply a convenience for programmers.

(There precedents for doing this in CSS/HTML, and prior to that in X11.  And it may well be that the JavaFx API designers borrowed the idea from these or other places.  However, the primary *motivation* is the same: programmer convenience.)

---

A secondary question:

> How about the [`Color`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html) class itself?  [Colour or Color](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/color-colour/)?

Unfortunately, it wouldn't work.  In Java, the following defines two distinct classes:

```
  public class Color {
     // fields, methods
  }

  public class Colour {
     // equivalent fields, methods to above.
  }
```

These classes are NOT assignment compatible, and a method that took a `Color` parameter would not accept a `Colour` parameter, and vice versa.  (You could declare one as a subclass of the other, but you would still end up with a type asymmetry, which would make one of the classes inadvisable in practice.)

Java does not have a way to implement type aliases.

Comment: Interesting. Than how about the [Color](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html) class itself? [Colour or Color?](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/color-colour/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that CSS/HTML does the same see https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp so it is common knowledge and for the CSS-Engine it can just make the name from the JavaFX-CSS to a constant.